C# filesystemwatcher not triggering for all files in watch folder
I am using C# filesystemwatcher to monitor a folder for new files that are generated from two web sites running on the same machine.  Sometimes new files trigger my event handler and sometimes they do not.
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = "c:/inetpub/websites/site1/PDF/Source",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
    Filter = "*.*"
};
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnNewFileCreated);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 

When I examine the properties of the new files, the only real difference is
the Details->Owner which are set to the web site names.
The files from site1 are processed, but the files with site2 are not.
I can copy and paste the site2 file in explorer and then it is acted on.
I can try moving the folder to a c:/temp folder but this did not make much sense to do so.
Are there any ideas on what is going on?
Any tips will be appreciated.
Thanks - Steve

Have tried adding NotifyFilters.FileName to the filter? Do both acutally save files in the same exact folder, or some subfolder? If that's the case, add .IncludeSubdirectories = true

That's a quite unusual way for writing a path in Windows. But anyway: Does site2 do anything differently when writing those files? Are they closed properly?

@pop, please, subscribe watcher to Error event and log error, maybe it will help to understand the issue. And if I do not mistake, after any error in fsw he must be recreated, because it will stop firing events

@Jimi - yes, both sites write to the same folder, the base folder I am watching

@OlehIvanitskyy - I added the following lines (without any luck)
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnNewFileCreated);
watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

@Fildor Site2 is a clone of Site1, but I will double check to make sure they are closed properly
